# Update Table based of another with one to many relationship. No cursors

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update

[image: Table Example]

I have these two tables and some example data that is in SQL Server.

The `Rules` table is just a `SELECT DISTINCT (DataSource_Id, LocationCode, WarehouseCode, WarehouseName, MTO_Regional)` of the `Inventory` table.

I want to update the `SS_Value` column in the `Rules` table based on the `MTO_MTS` value in `Inventory` where/if there is a value in any of the three 'SSIn...' columns.

**Example:** The 1st record in the Rules table would grab the first MTO_MTS value in the Inventory table that matches up based on (DataSource_Id, LocationCode, WarehouseCode, WarehouseName, MTO_MTSRegional) and has one 'SSIn...' column that is not 0.

So it could grab either of the first two records in Inventory since those 5 columns match, and at least one of the SSIn.. columns is a non-zero

**What I've tried so far:**

I have tried using a cursor but there are millions of records so can't handle it. I'm trying to construct a update statement but can't figure out the syntax.

```
UPDATE Rules r
SET SS_Value = (SELECT TOP(1) MTO_MTS FROM Inventory ip
                WHERE r.DataSource_Id = ip.DataSource_Id
                AND r.LocationCode = ip.LocationCode 
                AND r.WarehouseCode = ip.WarehouseCode
                AND r.WarehouseName = ip.WarehouseName
                AND r.MTO_MTSRegional = ip.MTO_MTSRegional 
                (ip.SafetyStockInKLG <> 0 OR ip.SafetyStockInLTR <> 0 OR ip.SafetyStockInUnits <> 0)
```

Something in this general idea I thought might work, but I can't get the syntax right.

I also tried the syntax like:

```
UPDATE Rules
SET ip.SS_Value
FROM InventoryProduction ip 
INNER JOIN Rules
```

I run into trouble with the scope of the tables in the queries, and getting the values from the row that is being updated to apply to the WHERE clauses.

Comment: And which of those 3 rows is the first?, how do you order them? (please don't say "because it's the first", we need a way to order them)

Comment: I'm not sure I 100% understand your question. But, the there isn't a set order to the Inventory table that I know of, it's just whenever that record was inserted into the database, and there is an incremented Id column. Of the rows that fit the criteria, it will not matter which one you grab. If that doesn't answer your question let me know and I can try to understand better.

Comment: "the 1st record in the Rules table would grab the **first** MTO_MTS value in the Inventory table", so, which one is the first row there?, there are 3 options

Comment: I meant that the 1st record in the Rules table would grab any record that matches the criteria. So it could grab either of the first two records in Inventory since those 5 columns match, and at least one of the SSin.. columns is a non-zero

Answer (score 0):

What does "first MTO_MTS value" mean?

This would be one way, written as a SELECT, assuming "first" means "minimum". Use this to verify that it's giving what you want, then turn into an UPDATE:

```
SELECT
 Rules.DataSourceID,
 Rules.LocationCode,
 Rules.WarehouseCode,
 Rules.WarehouseName,
 Rules.MTO_MTSRegional,
 SS_Value = MIN(Inventory.MTO_MTS)
FROM Rules
INNER JOIN Inventory
 ON Rules.DataSource_Id = Inventory.DataSource_Id
  AND Rules.LocationCode = Inventory.LocationCode 
  AND Rules.WarehouseCode = Inventory.WarehouseCode
  AND Rules.WarehouseName = Inventory.WarehouseName
  AND Rules.MTO_MTSRegional = Inventory.MTO_MTSRegional 
  (Inventory.SafetyStockInKLG <> 0 OR Inventory.SafetyStockInLTR <> 0 OR Inventory.SafetyStockInUnits <> 0)
GROUP BY
 Rules.DataSourceID,
 Rules.LocationCode,
 Rules.WarehouseCode,
 Rules.WarehouseName,
 Rules.MTO_MTSRegional
```

Comment: First may have not been the best word...it doesn't matter which record I grab, if they fit the criteria they should all be the same. So I could grab any from the result set given everything matches.

Answer (score 0):

First step selects only one row that can be used in update. You can add more columns in ORDER BY of ROW_NUMBER(). It changes cl output. I hope it works.

```
with cl
as
(SELECT MTO_MTS, ip.DataSource_Id, ip.LocationCode, ip.WarehouseCode, ip.WarehouseName,  ip.MTO_MTSRegional, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MTO_MTS ORDER BY DataSource_Id) rn
FROM Inventory ip inner join Rules r on
r.DataSource_Id = ip.DataSource_Id
AND r.LocationCode = ip.LocationCode 
AND r.WarehouseCode = ip.WarehouseCode
AND r.WarehouseName = ip.WarehouseName
AND r.MTO_MTSRegional = ip.MTO_MTSRegional 
where  (ip.SafetyStockInKLG <> 0 OR ip.SafetyStockInLTR <> 0 OR ip.SafetyStockInUnits <> 0)
)

UPDATE r
SET SS_Value = cl.MTO_MTS
from Rules r inner join cl on r.DataSource_Id = cl.DataSource_Id
AND r.LocationCode = cl.LocationCode 
AND r.WarehouseCode = cl.WarehouseCode
AND r.WarehouseName = cl.WarehouseName
AND r.MTO_MTSRegional = cl.MTO_MTSRegional 
where cl.rn = 1
```